# Creating different dataframes in for loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a series of lists **(list1,list2,list3,...,listn)** having similar structure and different info.

What I want to do is **taking these lists in a dataframe** form and dropping variables I don't need, in a for loop.

At the end of this, I'd like to have (df1,...,dfn), derived from the lists.

I tried with:

```
for (list in c("list1","list2"...,"listn")){
  for (i in (1:n)){
    assign(paste0("DF", i)) <- plyr::ldply(list)
    DFi = DFi[,c("tokeep1",..."tokeepn")]
  }
}
```

I guess this code is not quite right, and in fact it s not working.

I always get stuck on similar issues (creating a sequence of different df in a for loop) and didn't find a solution yet, so though might be helpful to ask.

Thanks,
Ciao

Comment: The `assign` bit here fundamentally doesn’t work this way, both conceptually and in practice. *Do not* create multiple variables with numbers appended. Instead, use a list. I.e. have `DF = list()` and assign to `DF[[i]]` inside the loop. Better yet, merge these data frames into one large table. Attempting to create variables in a loop is a surprisingly common mistake. But it’s *never the right approach*.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Konrad. It is way better to assign the results of your operations to a list, from which you can access the desired data frame simply with `[[]]`. Here an example :

```
l1 <- list(a=1:10,b=2:11,c=3:12)
l2 <- list(d=1:10,e=2:11,f=3:12)
l3 <- list(g=1:10,h=2:11,i=3:12)

tokeep <- function(x){as.data.frame(x)[,c(1,3)]}

dfs <- lapply(list(l1,l2,l3), tokeep)
#access to object inside the list
df1 <- dfs[[1]]
```